# What is the AFNetworking 2 equivalent to ASIHTTPRequest setMaxConcurrentOperationCount

Tags: objective-c, http, afnetworking-2, nsurlsession

I was trying to limit the max connections but couldn't find the method. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably what you want to do is to set a custom `NSURLSessionConfiguration` by creating your own `AFURLSessionManager` with `initWithSessionConfiguration:`.

The session configuration allows you to set `HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost`.

If you're using `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` then you can get its `operationQueue` and set `maxConcurrentOperationCount` on it.